# Error when trying to synthesize Verilog code for DE1SoC?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I am trying to instantiate a VHDL component in a Verilog design as a part of testing a divide function in another complex design. Getting syntax error:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at deldel.v(29) near text:
>   "[";  expecting ")".......

My VHDL file:

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity divide_test is
    port(
            odabir      : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
            rezultat    : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
            );
end divide_test;

architecture behavioral of divide_test is

    constant deljenik0  : unsigned(23 downto 0) := x"000999"; --2457
    constant deljenik1  : unsigned(23 downto 0) := x"000FA7"; --4007
    constant deljenik2  : unsigned(23 downto 0) := x"000288"; --648
    constant delilac        : unsigned(23 downto 0) := x"000015"; --21

    signal rez_temp : unsigned(23 downto 0);
    signal od_temp  : integer range 0 to 3;

begin
    od_temp <= to_integer(unsigned(odabir));
    rezultat <= std_logic_vector(rez_temp(9 downto 0));
    deljenje: process(od_temp)
    begin
        case  od_temp is
            when 0 => rez_temp <= x"000000";
            when 1 => rez_temp <= deljenik0/delilac; --150
            when 2 => rez_temp <= deljenik1/delilac; --200
            when 3 => rez_temp <= deljenik2/delilac; --32
        end case;
    end process;

end behavioral;
```

My Verilog file:

```
//=======================================================
//  This code is generated by Terasic System Builder
//=======================================================

module deldel(

    //////////// LED //////////
    output           [9:0]      LEDR,

    //////////// SW //////////
    input            [9:0]      SW
);



//=======================================================
//  REG/WIRE declarations
//=======================================================




//=======================================================
//  Structural coding
//=======================================================

divide_test u0(
    .odabir[1] (SW[0]),
    .odabir[0] (SW[1]),
    .rezultat[0] (LEDR[0]),
    .rezultat[1] (LEDR[1]),
    .rezultat[2] (LEDR[2]),
    .rezultat[3] (LEDR[3]),
    .rezultat[4] (LEDR[4]),
    .rezultat[5] (LEDR[5]),
    .rezultat[6] (LEDR[6]),
    .rezultat[7] (LEDR[7]),
);

endmodule
```

Verilog file is generic, created from "DE1SoC_SystemBuilder". I am trying to connect SW0 and SW1 from DE1Soc board to select one from three operation and show the result with eight LEDs on DE1Soc board!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that you should not use square brackets for the instance port names (`odabir` and `rezultat`) in the Verilog module.  You should not split out the bits of the signals in the instance port names.  Refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.3.2.2 *Connecting module instance ports by name*, which states:

> The port_name shall be the name specified in the module declaration.
>   The port name cannot be a bit-select, a part-select, or a
>   concatenation of ports.

You could use square brackets for the connecting signals (`SW` and `LEDR`).  However, since the signals are all 10 bits wide, it is simpler to just use the signal name:

```
divide_test u0 (
    .odabir   (SW),
    .rezultat (LEDR)
);
```

Note that you can use a range specifier for the connecting signals (`SW`, for example):

```
divide_test u0 (
    .odabir   (SW[9:0]),
    .rezultat (LEDR[9:0])
);
```

You can have any valid expression for the connecting signals (inside the parentheses).

Answer (score -1):

I find an answer! Originaly my ports:

```
    odabir      : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    rezultat    : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
```

was two and eight bits wide, respectively:

```
    odabir      : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
    rezultat    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
```

I change that in process to figure it out error code; trying to match lenght with De1Soc board ports SW and LEDR.
The solution code will be:

```
divide_test u0(
     .odabir   ({SW[1], SW[0]}),
     .rezultat ({LEDR[7], LEDR[6], LEDR[5], LEDR[4], LEDR[3], LEDR[2], LEDR[1], LEDR[0]})
);
```

Still I didnt find out why I cant split bits of ports od divide_test module that is being instantiate!?